# Meteor Spacebars custom split helper not rendering

Tags: javascript, meteor, spacebars

I'm trying to roll a custom helper to convert a string like this:

```
category = "Technology, Programming, Food, Cats";
```

Into an array. So far I have got:

PostItem.js

```
Template.postItem.helpers({
    split: function(stringCategory){
        //split the string based on , and " ".
        var cat = stringCategory.split(/,| /);
        window.console.info(cat);
        return cat;
    }
});
```

And the problem is when rendering, I don't know what else to try, but this code:

PostItem.html

```
    {{#each split category}}
        {{cat}}
    {{/each}}
```

It doesn't return anything at all... Can someone help me out?

Comment: "cat" is supposed to be a template?  You should have a > on the lefthand side if you're calling a template.

Comment: Nope, I'm trying to render `return cat;` from the template helper. Im trying to print it as a property

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take a look at [Nested sub-expressions](https://github.com/meteor/meteor/blob/devel/packages/spacebars/README.md#nested-sub-expressions). This is supported since v1.2.

Your `split` helper isn't returning after taking `category` as a parameter, therefore, you can update your template to use sub expressions.

```
{{#each (split category)}}
    {{cat}}
{{/each}}
```

Comment: Thank you for helping and for pointing out the docs! I needed to add also  `cat: function(){
  return this.split();
 }` to my helper function.